# How to add app to a site collection from app catlog programmatically in o365

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I want to add apps to a site collection  from app catlog programmatically

Comment: May I know the reason behind programmatically adding from App Catalog? Can't you use app scoped deployment? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179896.aspx

Comment: through CSOM or JSOM

Comment: We are automating   apps installation  to app catalog using power shell ,so apps should made be available in all sites when they are deployed to app catalog,since we have lot apps which should be made available when sites are created.So  need automation for same

Comment: I guess you have to iterate throught the sites or you can go to each app installed in App Catalog, click on Deployment, and install them in all the site collections present in tenant. But yes this is manual.

Comment: Power shell would also be fine